# How to use Process Monitor to find which process is deleting directory?

Tags: windows-10, process-monitor

I want to use [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to find [which process is deleting my temp folder](https://superuser.com/q/1502272/93604). I ran Process Monitor for the first time, and there's lot of options and new concepts (it's probably very powerful).

Could you please tell me **in a few simple steps, how can I monitor which process is deleting particular folder? With as least CPU overhead as possible** (I see it is monitoring hundreds different events per second!)

Comment: Have you tried adding delete events into the event log?

Comment: Reminder: you may also try to use Windows Resource Monitor disk activity subwindow for this if this happens in some relatively expected moment.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a filter on that folder. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to open the Filter dialog (or use the toolbar button). Select *Path* is *[Your directory]* then *Include*, and click on the *Add* button.

[image]

To specifically monitor *deletes* only, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/150301/how-do-i-log-which-process-is-deleting-a-file-on-windows-xp).

Comment: Thanks Berend, but what does it mean, "path is"? Path of what?

Comment: The path of whatever file or directory the event took place on. In your case, the directory that was deleted. See also the *path* column in the main Procmon window.

Comment: OK, but this shows also my program writing into that directory.... can I filter just the deletion of the dir?

Comment: @Tomas Yes, I added a link to a different question

Answer (score 0):

To show all File Activity you also can 'unselect' everything but the

"Show File System Activity" in the selection boxes as shown here.

[image]